# chef recipe FileEdit insert_line_after_match and insert_line_if_no_match

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I want to edit file using chef cookbook recipe.
The file appears now as,

```
[attribute1]
foo=bar
[attribute2]
....
```

I want to change it like:

```
[attribute1]
foo=bar
newfoo=newbar
[attribute2]
....
```

So basically, I want to add a line if it does not exist in the file and I want to add it after a particular line in that file.

I found 2 options under `Class: Chef::Util::FileEdit` which could be useful here `insert_line_after_match` and `insert_line_if_no_match`. But I want an option which can perform both of the actions. If I use `insert_line_after_match`, it works for first run but for next run it just keep adding lines even if line is already in the file. And `insert_line_if_no_match` adds line at the end of file if line does not exist in file but I want to add line after particular line in that file.

I am bit new to chef recipes. Is there any solution to solve above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not editing files, but rather overwriting them. You should create a template or a file inside the cookbook and then using `template` or `cookbook_file` resource overwrite the file on the machine with the one from cookbook.

Your config file looks similar to [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml), so you can also use [toml-rb](https://rubygems.org/gems/toml-rb) gem to generate this file from json (data bag) or attributes like that:

```
chef_gem 'toml-rb' do
  compile_time false
end

file '/path/to/file.conf' do
  content( lazy do
    require 'toml'
    "# This file is managed by Chef\n" +
    TOML.dump( my_json )
  end )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty please don't use FileEdit. It is an internal API and *not* intended for public use. What you want is the `line` cookbook, specifically the `replace_or_add` custom resource. Make sure you craft your regexp very carefully.

In general we do not recommend this kind of management style as it is very brittle and easily broken by unrelated changed. A better option is to use a `template` resource or similar to manage the whole file in a convergent manner.